# C++ Expression Templates - Why the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, expression-templates

I recently stumbled across expression templates in C++. There is one thing that I do not quite understand about their implementation, and that is why the base class is necessary (from which all other objects relating to template expression derive in a CRTP manner). A simple example that does addition and scalar multiplication on vectors (objects of type `Vec`, without base class):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vec
{
    vector<double> data;
public:

    template<typename E>
    Vec(E expr)
    {
        data = vector<double>(expr.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < expr.size(); i++)
            data[i] = expr[i];
    }
    Vec(int size)
    {
        data = vector<double>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            data[i] = i;
    }
    double operator [] (int idx) {
        return data[idx];
    }

    int size() { return data.size(); }

    bool operator < (Vec &rhs)
    {
        return (*this)[0] < rhs[0];
    }

    bool operator > (Vec &rhs)
    {
        return (*this)[0] > rhs[0];
    }

};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
class VecAdd
{
    E1 vec_expr1;
    E2 vec_expr2;

public:
    VecAdd(E1 vec_expr1, E2 vec_expr2) : vec_expr1(vec_expr1), vec_expr2(vec_expr2)
    {}

    double operator [] (int idx) { return vec_expr1[idx] + vec_expr2[idx]; }
    int size() { return vec_expr1.size(); }
};

template<typename E>
class ScalarMult
{
    E vec_expr;
    double scalar;

public:
    ScalarMult(double scalar, E vec_expr) : scalar(scalar), vec_expr(vec_expr)
    {}

    double operator [] (int idx) { return scalar*vec_expr[idx]; }
    int size() { return vec_expr.size(); }
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
VecAdd<E1, E2> operator + (E1 vec_expr1, E2 vec_expr2)
{
    return VecAdd<E1, E2>(vec_expr1, vec_expr2);
}

template<typename E>
ScalarMult<E> operator * (double scalar, E vec_expr)
{
    return ScalarMult<E>(scalar, vec_expr);
}

int main()
{
    Vec term1(5);
    Vec term2(5);

    Vec result = 6*(term1 + term2);
    Vec result2 = 4 * (term1 + term2 + term1);

    //vector<Vec> vec_vector = {result, result2};     does not compile
    vector<Vec> vec_vector;

    vec_vector = { result2, result };   //compiles

    vec_vector.clear();
    vec_vector.push_back(result);
    vec_vector.push_back(result2);      //all this compiles

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        cout << result[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles (except for the indicated line), and it evaluates the simple expressions in the main function without fault. If the expressions get assigned to an object of type `Vec` and assign their contents to a `Vec` object, getting destroyed in the process in any case, why is it necessary for a base class? (as shown in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) Wikipedia article)

**EDIT:**

I know this code is a bit messy and bad (copying where unnecessary, etc.) but I am not planning on using this specific code. This is just to illustrate that expression templates work in this example without the CRTP base class - and I am trying to figure out exactly why this base class is necessary.

Comment: What is `E expr`? If it's a data structure, why do you copy it as a parameter and then again in the function? Why not use resize or the assign function (depending on valid types of E) in the function? Why not use `vector<T>::size_type` to store the type of the vector? I don't understand the logic of your < > operators. Vector already supports < > operators for lexicographic comparisons.

Comment: Your `operator+` matches, well, about everything under the sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
VecAdd<E1, E2> operator + (E1 vec_expr1, E2 vec_expr2)
```

will match for *any* user-defined types, not merely expression types. When instantiated with non-vector types, it will then likely fail. This interacts very badly with other C++ types, quite possibly including standard library types, which provide their own custom `operator +` and may rely on inexact matches resolving to their own `operator +` after implicit conversions.

Making `operator +` only available for `VecExpression<E>` avoids that problem.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So that's the main reason for the base class in just about all the examples I see on expression templates? Do you know why that one line where I try to initialize the vector with an initialization list does not compile?

Comment: @KonradKapp That compiles just fine for me with GCC and with clang. I don't see an immediate problem that might only surface in other compilers either, but I may be overlooking something simple.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. But anyway, the main reason to use the base class is that which you have mentioned in your original answer (so it doesn't match any other data types)?

Comment: @KonradKapp I haven't looked at the details too much, but I think your main approach could well work aside from that one thing, yes.